The unit test is not running correctly; no matter how I assert, it always passes
@SpringBootTest(classes =  {DemoApplication.class}, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MockMvcTestor {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private FriendshipService friendshipService;

    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    @Test
    @DisplayName("测试 POST 创建好友关系接口")
    public void testFriendController_ValidUserId() throws Exception {
        // 模拟 userService 的行为
        when(userService.getUser(1)).thenReturn(new User()); // 返回一个有效用户
        when(userService.getUser(2)).thenReturn(new User()); // 返回一个有效用户
        when(friendshipService.getFriendshipByTwoUserId(1, 2)).thenReturn(null); // 模拟没有好友关系

        // 执行 POST 请求
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/friendship/BuildRelations")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                        .param("userId1", "1")
                        .param("userId2", "2"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.code").value(0)) // 验证返回的 code
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.message").value("Susad")) // 验证返回的 message
                .andReturn();
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("测试 POST 创建用户接口")
    public void testAddUser_ValidUser() throws Exception {
        // 创建 UserDTO 对象
        UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO();
        userDTO.setUsername("testuser");
        userDTO.setPassword("password");
        userDTO.setGender("Male");
        userDTO.setEmail("test@example.com");
        userDTO.setStatus("Active");

        // 模拟 userService.addUser() 方法，不返回任何值
        doNothing().when(userService).addUser(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(byte[].class));

        // 创建一个模拟的文件
        MockMultipartFile avatarFile = new MockMultipartFile("avatorPic", "avatar.jpg", MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE, "dummy data".getBytes());

        // 发送 POST 请求
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/users/addUser")
                        .file(avatarFile)
                        .param("username", userDTO.getUsername())
                        .param("password", userDTO.getPassword())
                        .param("gender", userDTO.getGender())
                        .param("email", userDTO.getEmail())
                        .param("status", userDTO.getStatus()))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.code").value(0))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.message").value("fal"));
    }


}

Here is my unit testing code and I'm doing devops to deploy the project to my server. My issue is that when the workflow reaches this step
    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn clean package

the output always shows:
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Even if I use a value "fal" which doesn't exist in the second test method, the testing still passed.
I want to figure out why the testing cannot operate normally.

Could it be that your tests are not unit tests but integration tests? Try mvn install.

yes, it's more suitable to call it integration test. And i run mvn install and still get  Results:
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.4.2:jar (default-jar) @ demo ---

Are you sure that the 2 tests it runs includes the test you've shown here? Try deleting this test and see if it still says 2 tests run.

Could you share your unit test setup? how are you injecting userService in your test class?

sorry for replying so late. I have modified the content. I use the @MockBean to inject my userService and use doNothing().when(userService) to setup the action of userService

you are right  k314159. the name of this test class has problem. it should end with Tests not Testor. Therefore they are not executing when mvn package. the two tests belong to the other test class.
